# find value within specific columns of named tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im doing a check for the value in C2 in a table (call it M1table), using this part of the formula:

(C$2=M1table)

Whole formula:
=RIGHT(INDEX(M1table,(SUMPRODUCT((C$2=M1table)*ROW(M1table))-ROW(M1table)),20),1)

How do I specify columns instead of checking the whole table? Unfortunately I don't have named columns, is there a way to do it with column number (look for value of C2 in 2nd to 8th column)? If using column names is the only way, I can name them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If `M1table` is a ***real*** Excel table, then the column header is the name and you can reference like `M1table[colName]`
- If `M1table` is just a range, and not a real table, then you can use the `INDEX` function to reference a single column. eg: for the 2nd column in the table:

  `C$2=INDEX(M1table,0,colNumber)`
- For columns 2-8 you could use:

  `=$C2=INDEX(M1table,,2):INDEX(M1table,,8)`

Comment: Appreciate it Ron, they are real tables, does your post mean I can only reference them using column headers?

Comment: @Dergyll No, you can use numbers or multi-column structured references.

Comment: Thank you Ron, just got it to work with your tip, appreciate you breaking it down for me!